# How to consume an internal REST service with a proxy approach?

Tags: spring-boot

I've developed a rest controller and I have that controller's API interface.

Now, in order to call it I could use the canonical RESTTemplate but I was wondering if there was something like an automatic proxy for REST.

Something like this:

```
@MyProxy(remoteAddr="http://serveraddr:8080/)
public class MyService implements RestApi{


}
```

And use it like this:

```
myService.aGetApi("foo");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Spring Cloud OpenFeign](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-openfeign#overview) project was created for this task.

A [simple example](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/feign-eureka) of using.

You can also implement a proxy service using the [Spring Cloud Gateway](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway) project.